# Rearrange the List based on one its value in Java

Tags: java, list, methods

Authoring an Java method which takes List as parameter(MasterList) and returns another list(ExpectedList).

```
MasterList: 
{ 
    (ID :abc123, Count: 20),
    (ID :abc122, Count: 19),
    (ID :abc122, Count: 20),
    (ID :abc122, Count: 18),
    (ID :abc121, Count: 21),
    (ID :abc120, Count: 21),
    (ID :abc120, Count: 20)
}
```

Each object in List have two variables:

1. ID (String)
2. Count (Number)

The logic which I'm trying to achieve is:
when the `MasterList` has more than one object where ID is same then consider only particular object whose count is greater. Means
ID: `abc122` has 3 objects, so I'll consider only (ID :abc122, Count: 20), because Count is higher among objects whose ID:abc122.
At the end the method should return

```
ExpectedList:
    {
        (ID :abc123, Count: 20),
        (ID :abc122, Count: 20),
        (ID :abc121, Count: 21),
        (ID :abc120, Count: 21)
    }
```

Comment: If you don't know how to solve a problem it is a good solution to show us your existing code and tell us what your problem exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

Stream over your list and collect your objects grouping by `ID` and mapping to the object with max count using `Collectors.maxBy` to get a `Map<String,Optional<MyObject>>`. Stream over the values unwrap the optional and collect to list:

```
List<MyObject> result = 

list.stream()
    .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    MyObject::getId, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getCount))))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```